# How do you add a custom tab to Wordpress post editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment there are two tabs in the post editor  Visual and HTML.

Is there a hook that allows for another tab to be added?

If so, what is it?

Additional info:

So, let's say the content of the post is an address.

The additional tab will contain the form for the person to fill in. When the post is updated, the person's answers will be stored as the post content. (pre-formatted with a template created by me)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that 3rd tab?

Comment: I want to add a content template. I could use a metabox for the same purpose. The reason why I want a third tab is that the new tab's content is what the post would be.

Hmm... a work around could be a custom post type and then simply replace the editor completely.

Comment: It is really not clear what you refer as *"what the post would be"* ... And for a good answer, this info is kind of fundamental. ... Please, add new information to the Question itself, you are free to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13811578/edit) it whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo, just added more info.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no hook to do this. But note that the two tabs (HTML and Visual) are treated differently than the rest of the TinyMce buttons (which can be set through options). Visual and HTML tabs can even be placed beside the editor and controlled with JavaScript to produce the same effect on the editor (switch its view from HTML to text and vice and versa).

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you know how to add another tab to it? Possibly using javascript?

Comment: You need to explain what sort of tab you want to add. Visual and HTML tab control the display of the editor's content. What is your 3rd tab going to do?

Comment: just added the reason to the original post. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the HTML and Visual controls can control the editor view:

```
            $('a.toggleVisual').click(
                function() {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
                }
            );

            $('a.toggleHTML').click(
                function() {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
                }
            );

        });
```

You see that basically, the difference between the two views is just adding or removing controls to leave the raw HTML view or to transform it. But you could add a button just beside. This is the code I use myself to display the tabs:

```
 <p align="right"><a class="button toggleVisual">Visual</a><a class="button toggleHTML">HTML</a></p><textarea rows="10" class="foo" id="editorid" name="editorname" style="width:100%%;">Text area content</textarea>
```

So you could just add another tab like this:

```
<p align="right"><a class="button toggleTemplate">Your Template Tab</a><a class="button toggleVisual">Visual</a><a class="button toggleHTML">HTML</a></p><textarea rows="10" class="foo" id="editorid" name="editorname" style="width:100%%;">Text area content</textarea>
```

And then bind to the click event to display another view, generated by your own routine...

Comment: Thanks, the thing is I'm adding this to a plugin. Since there is no hook I may use your script and inject it via javascript.