# WordPress add new tab to editor

Tags: php, wordpress

Look at this picture: https://pictr.com/images/2018/03/20/ad98176e507f9cc3e7b7268fb2b107ec.jpg
As you can see in the picture, I want to add a new tab to editor next to text and visual tab. Is there any hook for that? Or any other solution?!

Comment: Why don't you just click on Preview button on the right hand side? Its a native WordPress functionality...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811578/how-do-you-add-a-custom-tab-to-wordpress-post-editor

Comment: I don't know about wordpress but you can use bootstrap tools [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4br8sdq/)